# C# input matrix from text file crash

Tags: c#

here is my source code at the moment..

**CODE:**

```
static void InputValues()
{
  int row, col;
  string[] words;

  matrixName = fileIn.ReadLine();
  words = fileIn.ReadLine().Split(' ');
  dimenOne = int.Parse(words[0]);
  dimenTwo = int.Parse(words[1]);
  matrix = new int[dimenOne+1, dimenTwo+1];
  for (row = 1; row <= dimenOne; row++)
  {
    words = fileIn.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    for (col = 1; col <= dimenTwo; col++)
    {

      matrix[row, col] = int.Parse(words[col-1]);
    }
  }
}
```

My program will crash after it reads in the first value of `45` after

`matrix[row, col] = int.Parse(words[col-1]);` there are 3 spaces between values in the text file which is posted below. How do i populate the 2-d array without crashing?

**TXT FILE**

```
3
Matrix One
5 7
45   38    5   56   18   34    4
87   56   23   41   75   87   97
45   97   86    7    6    8   85
67    6   79   65   41   37    4
 7   76   57   68    8   78    2
Matrix Two
6 8
45   38    5   56   18   34    4   30
87   56   23   41   75   87   97   49
45   97   86    7    6    8   85   77
67    6   79   65   41   37    4   53
 7   76   57   68    8   78    2   14
21   18   46   99   17    3   11   73
Matrix Three
6 6
45   38    5   56   18   34
87   56   23   41   75   87
45   97   86    7    6    8
67    6   79   65   41   37
 7   76   57   68    8   78
21   18   46   99   17    3
```

Comment: Have you tried using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of `String.Split`? It automatically removes empty entries. Which I suspect your program is falling over, due to trying to parse something that's not an integer to an integer.

Comment: See the marked duplicate for a solution to splitting a string when there are a variable number of spaces between parseable data. If you need more help than that, improve your question by providing a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, stating clearly and precisely exactly what error occurs (including stack trace and any error message), and describing in detail what you've attempted to fix it, and what _specific_ difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Either test if you can convert the value to an integer (using TryParse) or better use a regular expression to parse the input string. Your problem is that the split function returns more results than you expect (can easily be seen if you set a breakpoint after words = filein....)

Comment: how do i use regex to parse the input string? i've never really used it before. i see split put 21 items into `words` array. when i desire it to put 7 items in, where 7 is the number of values in that row of the matrix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262480/whats-the-quickest-way-to-extract-a-5-digit-number-from-a-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why ReGex is better for parsing integers from string?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable number of spaces in your lines, you should eliminate them.

```
words = fileIn.ReadLine()
              .Split(' ')
              .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
              .ToArray();
```